# Custom post type pagination, single page issue

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, templates

After having problems getting pagination working at all for custom post types, I've read that the custom post type name and the page name cannot be the same.  So I set out from scratch:

I've created a custom post type of 'news-articles' (original I called it 'news' but got 404s on pagination) using the Custom Post Type UI plugin.

Next I created a template called `template-news.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: News
 *
 * Print posts of a Custom Post Type.
 */

get_header(); 
get_template_part( 'include/content', 'head' );

$type = 'news-articles';

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
   $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
   $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
   $paged = 1;
}

$args=array(
   'post_type' => $type,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'paged' => $paged,
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);

$temp = $wp_query;  // assign original query to temp variable for later use
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query($args);
?>

<div class="postcontent nobottommargin<?php if( semi_option( 'blog_sidebar' ) == 'left' ) { echo ' col_last'; } ?> clearfix">

<?php
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <div id="posts" class="small-posts clearfix">
        <?php
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            ?>

                            <div id="post-<?php $wp_query->ID; ?>" <?php post_class('entry clearfix'); ?>>
                                <?php
                                get_template_part( 'include/blog/news/post', 'standard' );
                                ?>
                            </div>
            <?php                
            endwhile;
            get_template_part( 'include/blog/navigation' );
            ?></div><?php
        else :
            get_template_part( 'include/blog/error' );
        endif;
        $wp_query = $temp;
        ?>
</div>
<?php if( semi_option( 'blog_sidebar' ) == 'left' ) { get_sidebar( 'left' ); } else { echo get_sidebar('news'); } ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'include/content', 'foot' ); ?>   
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Next I created a page called 'News' and assigned the template as 'News'.

At this point, if I view the news page, everything looks good.  I get pagination and it works.  However post title links are `/news-article/post-title` instead of `/news/post-title`.

If I try going to `/news/post-title` it just redirects to `/news-article/post-title`.

I tried setting 'Rewrite' to 'True' and 'Custom Rewrite Slug' to 'news' in CPT UI. At first glance this appears to have cured it, but it breaks pagination - I get a 404 on page 2.  I've tried refreshing the permalinks but still get the 404.

Comment: Why can't you use `archive-{post_type}.php` and `single-{post_type}.php` for this? See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I tried deleting the 'news' page, creating a custom post type of 'news' with archive set to true. Created archive-news.php. Pagination results in 404 :(

Comment: If you use the `archive-` and `single-` files you should not have a custom query in them.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to where to start now :(